# Center a non floating element inside an element having floated elements

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with aligning some elements inside a nav bar.

Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/flobar/b7nzR/

Here's the html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
#nav {
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;    
}

#menu {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}

#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
}

#settings {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

The issue is that the far right block is being pushed down by the center block, but I'm not sure why.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: why do you use `float: right`? When you want the divs to be in one line, use `float: left` on all of them

Comment: But I need the menu div on the left the logo div in the center and the settings div on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain you what's going on there, you have your first `div` set to `float: left;` which will float nicely, now your second `div` isn't floated either `left` or `right` so it's taking entire available horizontal space leading the third `div` to render below.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7nzR/2/)

```
#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

Now am aware of the fact that you want to center align your `#logo` so in this case, make your `#logo` `div` `position: absolute;`

```
#nav {
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;   
    position: relative; /* Be sure you use this else your div will fly out in the wild */
}

#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute; /* Takes your element out of the flow*/
    left: 50%; /* 50% from the left */
    margin-left: -100px; /* 1/2 of total width to ensure that it's exactly centered */
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7nzR/3/)

Comment: Awesome, I was thinking of positioning them all absolute, but I guess your version only requires me to change the logo's styling. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2575265 yes you can do that too, but don't forget to clear floats as you have floating elements, and also if you are going with absolute than don't forget to use `relative` on parent :) and you welcome ...

Answer (score 0):

You must float also the #logo;

```
 #logo {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/b7nzR/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but the logo needs to be aligned to the center.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #nav {
        height: 60px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;  
display:table;  
    }

    #menu {
        width: 70px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        float: left;
        background: #ccc;
display: inline-table;
    }

    #logo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
        background: #ccc;
display: inline-table;
    }

    #settings {
        width: 70px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        float: right;
        background: #ccc;
        display:inline-table
    }
```